# How to dynamically create EBS volume with Kubernetes Persistence Volume

Tags: kubernetes

I'm aware you can use aws cli to create ebs volume and then get the Volume ID and add to `PersistentVolume` config as below under the `volumeID`.

I don't want to use aws cli to create the ebs volume, My question is, how do I use Kubernetes to create this ebs volume dynamically without using the cli ?

```
apiVersion: "v1"
kind: "PersistentVolume"
metadata:
  name: "pv0001" 
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: "5Gi" 
  accessModes:
    - "ReadWriteOnce"
  awsElasticBlockStore: 
    fsType: "ext4" 
    volumeID: "volume-ID"
```

Answer (score 1):

By default this should be working on a decently provisioned cluster. Just have the storageClassName defined correctly on a matching PVC and a PV will et provisioned for it (no need to precreate PV object, just the claim)

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#persistentvolumeclaims

Comment: Thanks for commenting. If this is the case why did the documentation appear to mention many times that a PV object is required to create a volume and then a PVC to make a claim from the volume created by PV?

Comment: cause for manual management of PV that is exactly what is needed. Only if you deploy to an environment that has a dynamic volume provisioning capability can you leverage automatic PV creation for *some* PVC (with appropriate storageClassName)

Answer (score 0):

**Dynamic provisioning**

When none of the static PVs the administrator created matches a user’s `PersistentVolumeClaim`, the cluster may try to dynamically provision a volume specially for the PVC. This provisioning is based on `StorageClasses`: the PVC must request a class and the administrator must have created and configured that class in order for dynamic provisioning to occur. Claims that request the class `""` effectively disable dynamic provisioning for themselves

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#provisioning

Answer (score 0):

Follow this:
https://docs.docker.com/ee/ucp/kubernetes/storage/configure-aws-storage/

Basically, instances must have an IAM Role to create/attach/detach/delete volumes on their own.